# Restrict the domain of a relation in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I have a relation that is not well-founded call it r1. It is defined (implicitly) as a function:

`r1: a' => a' => bool`

However, I note that if I restrict the type to:

`r2: b' => b' => bool`

where b' is defined as the type a' with an additional constraint depending on r, this relation is actually well founded, and I can use this good property with theorems of the standard library.

**My example**

To be more precise, I'm using a predicate `finite_runs r s` to state that from state `s` I can only have a finite number of transitions (i.e. relations that start at `s` are terminating). Of course, if one takes the set of all states, from the fact, `finite_runs r s` I cannot deduce that for all states `s'` I have `finite_runs r s'`. However, I would need this last property to state that the relation `r` is well-founded in the set of all states.

But then, I realize that `r` is indeed well-founded if I restrict it to the set of states that are connected to `s` in some number of states. This can be easily shown because the inductive definition of `finite_runs` is

```
inductive finite_runs for r where
  "(⋀ s'. r s s' ⟹ finite_runs r s') ⟹ finite_runs r s"
```

So, in some proof I want to use the information that the well-foundedness of `r` over the set `{s'. r**  s s'}` gives me. However, there is no way in the theory Wellfoundedness that can help me. I would like for this case, to be able to say that type `b'` above is type `a'` with the additional restriction that `{s'. r**  s s'}` and then instantiate the theorems in Wellfoundedness for that relation.

How can I restrict a function's domain such as in the case above?

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't quite get your question. (Shouldn't it be `'a=>'a=>bool`, and `'b=>'b=>bool`?) Could you give more details? Have you tried connecting them with `wf_map_prod_image` and some injective function casting from the restricted to the bigger type?

Comment: @BenKeks many thanks for your comments. I have edited my question, I still need to check the theorems you suggest me

Comment: It's often rather impractical to encode local assumptions as type information. Can't you just restrict `r` to the part "behind" `s`? (Which is like assuming that `!!s'. r** s s'`.)

Comment: @BenKeks actually that's how I'm working this last hours. now I'm trying to liberate myself from the assumption (i don't know if this will be easy or not)

Comment: I'd be really interested in learning how you solve this! I ran into a related situation recently. There, I just proved that finite parts of a partial order will have maximal elements, which was all I needed. https://coupledsim.bbisping.de/isabelle/Finite_Partial_Order.html#finite_max This felt a little clumsy as I guess that Isabelle offers easier solutions by tapping into existing lemmas about well-foundedness and the like. But I don't know how either.